# how to redraw a polygon that completely self-intersects?

Tags: computational-geometry

The problem is to redraw a self-intersecting 2D polygon, whose border is always a separation line between its interior and its exterior and completely crosses itself in some points (that is, in those points, the polygon interior switches the side of the border, from left to right or vice versa).

What is the simplest algorithm that can do that?

The initial polygon (left) and the redrawn one (right):

[image: the initial polygon] 
[image: and the redrawn one].

I added another, a little more complicated example of an initial polygon, that is still very simple (it has only one self-intersection vertex) [in this third picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBg7F.jpg) where the polygon interior is filled (points A,B,C,D,E appear in alphabetic order initially when drawing the polygon border).

Comment: Do you mean redraw it so it no longer self-intersects?

Comment: the final result should always have the polygon interior  on the same side of its border.

Comment: so it sort of half-self-intersects itself.

Comment: i just thought myself of a "naive way" of doing that.

Comment: This appears to be an attempt to get SO users to do your homework.  Why don't you show what work you have done so that we know that you're actively approaching the problem ?

Comment: @Erica, please excuse my illiteracy.

Comment: the pictures present a very simple case. I know how to handle such a simple case but I do not know to handle the general case (a polygon that is arbitrarily complex, still its contour is always a border between its interior and its exterior).

Comment: sorry, the arrow tip of rightmost edge in the left picture is not correct.

Comment: it should obviously be reversed.

Comment: Do you want to find the intersection, and create two polygons (in the case showed above). Wouldn't the simple brute-force way just be to use a line intersection check between all non-neightbour edges? Insert a new vertex and create a new face.
Wikipedia has a fine article on line-line intersection (Google can find even more) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection

Comment: @ Anders Schou, thank you.

Comment: but my goal is not that. I want to understand the thinking behind the algo (preferably the simplest algo) that is able to redraw any 2D polygon, in a way that the result polygon has its interior always on the same side of the polygon border. do ypu know of such an algortihm ?

Comment: I would appreciate if someone could provide a link to a book or paper that explains that.

Comment: @Anders Schou.  ah, and if the initial poly has been drawn "in one move" (that is without interrupting the line drawn by "the pencil"), the result poly should also be drawable in one move (exactly as in the very simple case shown in the pictures).

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking isn't that simple.

You can use a sweepline procedure. The general principle is as follows.

When you draw an horizontal line across the polygon, it meets an even number of edges. Sorting the intersections from left to right, and linking them in pairs, you obtain interior segments.

If you do this for all positions of the horizontal, you will decompose the polygon in a number of monotone chains, i.e. polylines always going down.

When the polygon is simple, the chains appear in pairs at a vertex, disappear in pairs at another, and live their own lifes. But when the polygon is crossed, the chains can cross each other. This can be detected by the fact that from one position of the horizontal to the next, the ordering of intersections change.

Now you have to fix that by "uncrossing" the chains, which is done by splitting the edges at the intersection point.

[image]

I can't develop more here, try and lookup "sweepline algorithm".

Comment: thank you. for your colorful drawing and for phrasing your message in plain language (I am a fan of it, too).

Comment: @ Yves Daoust, thank you a lot. but my questions is about how to do the uncrossings (it is not about finding the self-intersections and inserting them, where that is necessary, in the initial polygon vertex list; so let's assume that edge splitting has already been done where necessary and the initial vertex list completed with the self-intersections is given ). could you now please tell further the idea the uncrossing should be based on and exemplify that by applying your approach to the example in my third picture ? in the same wonderful plain language PLEASE :)